# Why does vector::erase seem to cause a crash?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, erase

When `first1.erase(std::next(first1.begin(), i));` is removed the second loop is made, its a bit strange since `first2.erase(first2.begin() + 4, first2.end());` works okay

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> first1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> first2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> second;
    std::vector<int> third;

    for(size_t i = 4; i < first1.size(); ++i){
      auto child = first1[i];
      second.push_back(child);
      first1.erase(std::next(first1.begin(), i));
    }

    third.assign(first2.begin() + 4, first2.end());
    first2.erase(first2.begin() + 4, first2.end());

    std::cout << "Size of first: " << int (first1.size()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Size of second: " << int (second.size()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Size of first: " << int (first2.size()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Size of third: " << int (third.size()) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of first1: 5
Size of second: 1
Size of first2: 4
Size of third: 2
```

I expected `first1/second` to be the same as `first2/third`

you can test it here http://cpp.sh/9ltkw

Comment: there's no second loop, otherwise the size of `first1` would be 4 and size of `second` would be 2

Comment: It's a bad idea to modify a container while iterating it.  I suggest splitting the operation up.  Copy and then erase.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match what you're reporting. Your program doesn't "crash".

Comment: I forgot to stay away from modifying containers while iterating when possible... I haven't been getting any good sleep so my mind is a bit unstable

Comment: @Blastfurnace I said it seemed to cause a crash because i wasn't sure... all worked well when `erase` was commented out so I assumed it was doing something wrong and preventing the program from reaching the "second" iteration... in this case I believe the title matches as someone else might come across the same issue

Comment: My confusion was because the code reached the `std::cout` statements and produced output, just not what you expected. Usually a "crash" implies the program halts or abnormally terminates perhaps showing a fault or exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first iteration of the loop

```
for(size_t i = 4; i < first1.size(); ++i){
  auto child = first1[i];
  second.push_back(child);
  first1.erase(std::next(first1.begin(), i));
}
```

`i` will be equal to `5` and first1.size() also will be equal to 5. So only one element of the vector is erased.

You could rewrite the loop like

```
for(size_t i = 4; i != first1.size(); ){
  auto child = first1[i];
  second.push_back(child);
  first1.erase(std::next(first1.begin(), i));
}
```

to get the expected result.

In these statements

```
third.assign(first2.begin() + 4, first2.end());
first2.erase(first2.begin() + 4, first2.end());
```

there are assigned and erased 2 elements.